# how to use aidl-cpp to generate .aidl to c++ code

Tags: c++, aidl

1. What I need: compile .aidl file to c++ code
2. What I found: [Generating C++ Binder Interfaces with aidl-cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/brillo-m10-dev/docs/aidl-cpp.md)

   [AIDL compiler for C++ on Linux Desktop](https://github.com/hiking90/aidl-cpp)

3.What I did:I had clone the "aidl-cpp" on the second link,after viewing the many files in the project,I was missing.

---

Some doubt here:

1. Can I compile this project and use the target to compile my
   project?If yes,I need the whole android platformtsource code in my
   system path?Because I try to compile one single file main_java.cpp
   with g++ commandline , and it returns some "android-base" libs
   cannot find.
2. Or I can write my own cpp file to implement the interfaces defined
   in my .aidl files imitate the "aidl-cpp" project.This way I haven't
   tried.

What's the right way to meet my need?

Comment: Maybe I got some points.I need first compile the CMakeLists.txt use "cmake" commandline, and "make" to install,so I will get a excutable aidl-cpp file ,and use this to compile my .adil file to cpp file,I guess so.Now, I get some error about yy:parer when running "make" commandline.

Comment: To resolve problem above I have upgrade bison from 2 to 3 via homebrew But error comes still.I guess that's because of a custom class named Parser conflict with yy::parser.That error seems just related with class scope.

Comment: https://github.com/hiking90/aidl-cpp/issues/2  Anyone can help?

Comment: I use aidl-cpp work on the test source code,the header files were generated ,but when I import android.os.Bundle in the .aidl file,but append -I options to the aidl-cpp commandline ,it returns error.The -I options point to my android sdk source path.I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: You will need to have the Android source tree and compile the service _within_ the build tree if `aidl-cpp` is to be used. Hand-rolling your own interface implementations too would require the same Framework headers for compilation since `libbinder` isn't a part of any public SDK. Also check if NDK is an option from [here](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/aidl/aidl-backends)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use aidl of android sdk build-tools after 29.0.0.

```
aidl --lang=ndk <input.aidl>
```